# how to make has_block() see inside blocks too

Tags: functions, block-editor

I am using `has_block()` to check if post has a specific block type but it does not see blocks inside another blocks, like columns block. So, how to make it find a gallery inside the column?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should, because `has_block( 'gallery' )` uses <sup>[source](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/5.5.1/src/wp-includes/blocks.php#L316)</sup> `strpos()` to determine if the post content has the `<!-- wp:gallery` string.

Comment: Ok I asked wrong question. My problem is with rendering that gallery. I thought this is the issue but it is somewhere else...